# CSS hover inner element on outer hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like to apply the hover state to the inner input element of the following link by hovering the image:

```
<a href="#"><img  src="img.png">
    <div class="btn-u">Hackschnitzel</div>
</a>
```

So hovering the image should result in the same state as hovering the button (right state - button is green)

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS only?

EDIT: As the class for hover of `btn-u` already exists, I don't want to redefine those values and want to reference from `a:hover` to apply `btn-u:hover` as well

Comment: You've got invalid markup, `input` is not allowed within `<a>` elements.

Comment: Also, the duplicate title is a red-herring. It's the same exact concept, just different markup.

Comment: You are right, was just for the layout. Will change to plain div

Comment: Can you please add a link of the duplicates?

Comment: I updated the question to make my intentions more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `background-image` CSS property

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <input type="button" class="btn-u" value="Hackschnitzel" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  background-image: url('https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--pEKSmwzm--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/1414228815325188681.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
a:hover {
  background-image: url('http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/yahoo_logo_detail.png');
}

a input { color: #fff; font-weight: 700; background-color: #ff0000; }
a:hover input { background-color: #00ff00; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1oj3ddft/

### Edit 1 -

https://jsfiddle.net/1oj3ddft/1/

Comment: Please have alook at my updated question.

Comment: I think it is the same idea, please check the edit 1 of my anwser

Answer (score 1):

yes, just extend the css properties.

Here's an example, just add `a:hover .btn-u` to css what you want

```css
a:hover .btn-u{
  font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img  src="https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/bc85dff2b3dc44ddb9650e1659b1ad1e.png">
    <input type="button" class="btn-u" value="Hackschnitzel">
</a>
```

Comment: I updated the question please have a look again